# Rotate 2D shape whilst extruding for twisted geometry

Tags: three.js

I'm new to three.js and JavaScript. I'm trying to extrude a 2D square shape whilst rotating it about the extrusion axis like this: [twist extrude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSrQY.png)

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like you can extrude in the usual way and then apply a geometrical transformation with a shear matrix to get this effect with `geometry.applyMatrix(matrix)`.

I know that `THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames` implements information about the tangents, normals, binormals of a 2D shape as it carves out an extrude path.

Is there a way of hard coding tangents and binormials of a 2D shape whilst it's extruding to get this 'twisted' effect?

Is there a simpler way to get this effect in three.js?